# Laravel 5.3 - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Connection::resolverFor()

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I am trying to run the "composer update" command and I get the following error; How can I resolve this error?

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\fatalthrowableerr is]
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Connection::resolverFor()

Note: I deleted the vendor file and then I ran the "composer install" command but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

composer dump
composer install